# PHP PDO login form fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is actually one of my first times trying PDO and the password_verify function. I've read a few articles and started with a really basic login form withouth any password hashing. Just to start understanding the basics, however withouth luck.

It might be me on a Tuesday morning but i can't seem to find the error. I hope you guys can point me in the right direction.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Forgot the error. I get "Fail", so i assume it's somewhere in the password_verify function.

Here is my code:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" />

  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Inloggen" />
  <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      if(!empty($_POST['username']) && $_POST['password']) {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        try {
          $host    = 'localhost';
          $db      = 'pdotest';
          $user    = 'root';
          $pass    = '';
          $charset = 'utf8';

          $dsn  = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
          $opt  = [
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                  ];

          $pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

          $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username');
          $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
          $user = $stmt->fetch();
          if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
               if(password_verify($password, $user['password']))
               {
                  echo "Succesfully logged in!";
               }
               else
               {
                  echo "Fail";
               }
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
          $message = $e->getMessage();
        }
      }
    }
  ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Any error appearing?

Comment: @Tesseract O sorry forgot that, it returns "Fail". So I assume it's somewhere in the password_verify function.

Comment: is `$user['password']` a hash? How do you store the password?

Comment: check if if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ok then check this
password_verify($password, $user['password']) and in this function check your expected value ok

Comment: @Jens All passwords are stored in plain-text for now, i know this is not smart but it's one of my first times trying pdo and password_verify so i thought why not for now.

Comment: can you show your password_verify function?

Comment: @vaxzz Then read the php doc of [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php). second Parameter must be a hash

Comment: @Jens O god, I'm so sorry. Didn't read that and assumed i could just check passwords with it whether they are hashed or plain-text.

Comment: @vaxzz why you should call such method, if both are plain text strings. In this case a string equals is enough

Comment: How did u save the password?